# Hide table tr based in checkbox status even on AJAX load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, onchange

I would like to **hide** the table `tr` where the `tr`>`td` class is `status-locked` , **if checkbox is checked**.

I have an table which looks like this. It loads data from database using Ajax loader , so if its more than 4 product there would be a page 2 link. if page 2 link is clicked it loads the data using AJAX. The table only gets new data based on the AJAX loading data from database.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="product-toggle"  style="border: 1px  #000; background-color: #000;">

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="status-locked">text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td class="status-locked">text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button>1</button> <button>2</button>
```

Now i use **jquery** to hide the `tr` with an `td` that has `class="status-locked"` and it works.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#product-toggle').change(function(){
  if($(this).prop("checked")) {
     $('tr:has(td.status-locked)').hide();
  } else {
    $('tr:has(td.status-locked)').show();
  }
});
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
 <body> 
<input type="checkbox" id="product-toggle"  style="border: 1px  #000; background-color: #000;">

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>hide</td>
        <td>hide</td>
        <td>hide</td>
        <td class="status-locked">hide</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>hide</td>
        <td>hide</td>
        <td>hide</td>
        <td class="status-locked">hide</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <button>1</button> <button>2</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The **problem** is if the AJAX loads new data from `database` and the checkbox is checked the `tr`>`td`>`class="status-locked"`  shows?

I want the `tr` with an `td` with `class="status-locked"` to be hidden , always unless checkbox unchecked.

This Jquery works for page refresh but not on AJAX table load:

```
$(function(){        
$('#product-toggle')
  .prop('checked', localStorage.input === 'true')
  .on('change', function() {
     localStorage.input = this.checked;
     if (localStorage.input === 'true') {
       $('tr:has(td.status-locked)').hide();
     } 
  })
  .trigger('change');
});
```

Comment: You should add the change logic inside the ajax success callback too.. show us the ajax part

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki so i cant do it just using jquery? i have to add the change logic with the Ajax call?

Comment: You have to call it just after the ajax request, could you tell us how the ajax call trigger or do you have the control to edit it..

Comment: that is the big problem i dont have the control to edit the AJAX call.. that is why im trying this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to separate the logic like :

```
$( document ).ready(function () {
    toggleRow();
    $('#product-toggle').on('change', toggleRow);
});

function toggleRow() {
    if( $('#product-toggle').prop("checked") ) {
         $('tr:has(td.status-locked)').hide();
    } else {
        $('tr:has(td.status-locked)').show();
    }
}
```

Then use the `.ajaxComplete()` method that will be called after every ajax request :

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
  toggleRow();
});
```

Comment: i like this approuch, but `$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
  toggleRow();
});` is not working? how to add this in the same `js` file after `$( document ).ready(function () {...});` becuase i add it ass per your code but its asif  its not reading the function

Comment: using juery version jquery-1.11.0.min.js, oky ill do so

Comment: changed the function line to `  if($('#product-toggle').prop("checked")) {` and it worked, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are not selecting `td` element in your selector. Try to use `$('tr td.status-locked')`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#product-toggle').change(function(){
  if($(this).prop("checked")) {
     $('tr td.status-locked').hide();
  } else {
    $('tr td.status-locked').show();
  }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="product-toggle">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>hide</td>
        <td>hide</td>
        <td>hide</td>
        <td class="status-locked">hide</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>hide</td>
        <td>hide</td>
        <td>hide</td>
        <td class="status-locked">hide</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <button>1</button> <button>2</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this only hides the `td` i want to hide the `tr` that has an `td` with `class="status-locked"`

Comment: So, what is the problem ? You mentioned a Ajax call in the question but I couldn't see it.

Comment: cant duplicate an AJAX call in the snippet, the problem is everything works, meaning it hides the `tr` based on the `td` class if checkbox checked , but if i click on "button2" which loads the second table from database  which is an AJAX load the `tr`with the `td` that has class `class="status-locked"` shows and the checkbox is still checked so it should not show.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is triggered only when the checkbox, change. If you want to solve your problem, you need to write something like this in your javascript: `

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    hideShowRow();
    $('#product-toggle').change(function(){
      hideShowRow();
    });
});
function hideShowRow(){
      if($(this).prop("checked")) {
         $('tr:has(td.status-locked)').hide();
      } else {
        $('tr:has(td.status-locked)').show();
      }
}
```

` ... in this way you will be able to call your function,hideShowRow(), whenever you want. You can call it in document.ready, in the ajax.success  or wherever you want

Comment: But if i look at your code it is still based on the `change` event?

Comment: yes, it is based on change event, but it is separe logic: hideShowRow() can be called easily from outside the document.ready function... Can you show me please your code of the ajax call?

Comment: i understand and thanks, but got it working based on another answer. your code is correct you where just lacking the `ajaxComplete` function.